# C言語のポインターに詰まっています。

Tags: c

下記の結果で、文字化けをする。

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
char *in="abc";
char *out;
while(*out++ = *in++);
printf("%s\n",out);
return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

2つ問題があります。

1. 書き込む先のメモリが確保されておらず、`out`が初期化されていませんので、不明の場所に書き込むと，最悪プログラムが異常終了します。
2. 結果を表示するときの`out`が、文字終端の次を指しているので、そこにどんなデータがあるか予測できませんので、期待した結果が表示されません。

1の問題はメモリを確保してそのアドレスを`out`にセットします。

例：

```
char buf[10];
out = buf;
```

2の問題は、表示する際、メモリの先頭アドレスを`printf`に渡します。

例：

```
printf("%s\n", buf);
```

Answer (score 3):

修正方法はsoramimiさんが答えられているので、何が起こっているのかを説明します。

1. 初期状態

   ```
   'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'
    ↑ in "abc"の先頭を指している

    ↑ out 未初期化なのでどこを指しているか不定
   ```
2. `while(*out++ = *in++);`１周目、`a`を書き込んだので`while`ループを継続

   ```
   'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'
         ↑ in
   'a'
         ↑ out
   ```
3. `while(*out++ = *in++);`２周目、`b`を書き込んだので`while`ループを継続

   ```
   'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'
              ↑ in
   'a', 'b'
              ↑ out
   ```
4. `while(*out++ = *in++);`３周目、`c`を書き込んだので`while`ループを継続

   ```
   'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'
                   ↑ in
   'a', 'b', 'c'
                   ↑ out
   ```
5. `while(*out++ = *in++);`４周目、`\0`を書き込んだので`while`ループを終了

   ```
   'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'
                       ↑ in
   'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'
                       ↑ out
   ```

この状態で`printf("%s\n",out);`を実行するので、どこを指しているか不明なメモリの、まだ書き込んでない部分を出力する

---

というわけで、何が出力されるか全く不定です。当然、**文字化け**でもなんでもなく単なるプログラムのバグです。